# Show that circumcircle $\Delta MCD$ is constant.

Tags: geometry

Consider a circle $O$ with radius R. $A,B$ is constant point such that $AB\ne2R$, $C$ and $D$  are respectively in $(O)$ such that $AD//BC$ $(C,D\ne A,B)$, the intersection of $BD$ and $AC$ is $M$.The intersection of the tangent line at $A$ and the tangent line at $D$ is $I$. Show that circumradius 
$\Delta MCD$ is constant.
[image]

---

I proved $COMD$ is cyclic quadrilateral, then i draw $OM\perp ME$ to find radius of the circumcircle of $\Delta MCD$ but failed.Help me

Comment: @ John Omielan: Thx, i fixed.

Comment: The tangents at $A$ and $D$ (and, thus, the point $I$) don't seem to have anything to do with anything. Also, I believe you mean that the *circumradius* is constant; the *circumcircle* certainly isn't fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually,this is a very simple geometry problem,you are thinking too much.
The circumradius of $\triangle MDC$ is equal to $CD\over 2sin\angle {DMC}$.

Notice that $CD=AB$ is constant,and$\angle {DMC}=2\angle {ADB}$ is also constant.

Comment: Oh, thx you. I forgot that $a/sinA=2R$.